# SSH Port Forwarding Internal Details

Tags: http, ssh, port, portforwarding

This is more of a theory question for more understanding.

In order to do port forwarding we update `sshd_config` and provide the information of local port(a) and remote port(b) among which we need to perform forwarding. After this forwarding config is done, ssh tunnel will be used to forward packets between `a <-> b`.

But internally, how does this work? when I do `https://localhost:a`, how does packet move from port `a` to ssh tunnel port 22 and on the other side from port 22 to port `b`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested about the internals, openssh is the most popular implementation of SSH protocol and it is open source with code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/).

To answer a bit your question, it works as every other network communication. If you are not familiar with it, check how [network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) works. Port forwarding is doing just proxy between the ends and sends the data inside the encrypted channel, instead of outside as the direct socket would.

Anyway, it is easier to google a bit. Ubuntu has a nice explanation in their [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Port_Forwarding_Explained):

> To get the most out of port forwarding, it's helpful to know a bit about how the Internet works.
>
> The Internet assigns computers virtual "ports", a bit like the USB ports on the back of your computer:
>
> To let a digital camera share pictures with your PC, you connect the USB port on the camera to any USB port on the PC. The computer then talks to the camera about your photos, and shows you the result.
>
> To let a web server share pages with your PC, you connect the web server port on the server to any Internet port on the PC. The computer then talks to the server about your page, and shows you the result.
>
> Unlike a USB port, there is no physical component to an Internet port. There's no actual wire, or actual hole on the back of your computer. It's all just messages being sent over the Internet. Like other "virtual" computer concepts, Internet ports are just an analogy that help to explain what your computer is doing. Sometimes, that analogy breaks down:
>
> There are two types of Internet port: normal "TCP" ports and strange "UDP" ports (which won't be covered here).
>
> Unlike USB ports, every computer has exactly 65,535 numbered TCP ports, some of which have a special purpose. For example, port number 80 is your web server port, so your web browser knows it should connect to port number 80 in order to download a web page.
>
> Connections between Internet ports can be patched together, so a connection from computer A to computer B on port 12,345 could be patched through to port number 80 on computer C. This is known as port forwarding.